# Estou tendo erro com php no vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Ele me retorna esse erro aqui, **"phpcs não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes."** E fala que a origem é no **php sniffer (extensão)**.

Também um outro erro do php é que ele da **erro NOT FOUND 404** quando coloco o ip da maquina com **info.php[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]**

Comment: Olá @Samm você configurou corretamente as variáveis de ambientes?
Se já estiver configurada, basta você apertar **F1** no **vsCode** e pesquisar por **Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)**  ou **settings.json** quando abrir, caso não exista você vai adicionar **"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\php7.4\\php.exe"**, no caso você precisa adicionar o caminho do seu PHP que está instalado, no meu caso está no **Disco C**, pasta **php7.4**, depois que configurar faça o teste novamente... espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa ir para Meu Computador -> propriedades -> Configuração avançada do sistema

Agora clique em Variáveis ​​de Ambiente
Adicione ; C: \ xampp \ php no valor da variável de caminho

ou o caminho onde esta instalado seu php

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Veja resposta nesse tutorial!
Acredito que ele irá ajudar

https://qastack.com.br/programming/31291317/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-command-prompt